# angular bootstrap typeahead set ng-model to the object not a single field

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I'm using the angular bootstrap typeahead directive. Is there a way to select the whole selected object to be set in my `ng-model` instead of the string when i utilize typeahead?

e.g.

**mycontroller.js**

```
var getStates = function() {
   // calls rest service that pulls in states.json from some angular factory
}
var StateCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.states = getStates();

    $scope.submit = function () {
        // Should expect an Object and not the name of the state
        console.log($scope.states);
    }
}
angular.module('StateCtrl', []).controller(['$scope', StateCtrl]);
```

**states.json**

```
[
// i don't want just state.name i want everything
{name: Alabama, stateCode: 123, salesTax: .06}, 
{name: Arkansas, stateCode: 122, salesTax: .06},
{name: New York, stateCode: 120, salesTax: .10},
...
]
```

**index.html**

```
<input ng-model="selectedstate" uib-typeahead="state.name for state in states">
<!--- i want selectedState to be {{state}} and not {{state.name}} -->
<button ng-click="submit()">submit</button>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `uib-typeahead="state.name for state in states"` with `uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in states"`. This should do the work for you. Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lh380Agx4FIsMRDZMroJ?p=preview).

Comment: I think the ending part should be `state in states`

Comment: Yes, you are right. That is how it is in the example. I forgot it in the answer. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Relevant docs for this syntax: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select